# How to host an ASP.NET Core Web Application with enabled enforced encryption with Nginx?

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, hosting, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am a beginner and I am trying to host a .NET Core web application with enforced HTTPS enabled on Ubuntu Server. When I try to access my website from another computer I receive an error. However, when I create a project with enforced HTTPS `off` it works perfectly.

I need to have the enforced HTTPS turned `on` in the web application as I want to use the individual user account option, and for that, enforced HTTPS is needed.
I am using an Nginx server to make a reverse proxy for the web app.

After I run the `dotnet` command on Linux server and access the website, I receive this error in the Ubuntu server:

> ```
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>       Connection id "0HLNOTQ3C92Q3", Request id "0HLNOTQ3C92Q3:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: connectionString
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
>    at TurismRomaniaWebsite.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in D:\Proiecte C#\Turism Romania\TurismRomaniaWebsite\TurismRomaniaWebsite\Startup.cs:line 41
>    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
>    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
>    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
>    at lambda_method(Closure , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
>    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
>    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorPagePropertyActivator.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<CreateActivateInfo>b__1(ViewContext context)
>    at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyActivator`1.Activate(Object instance, TContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(Object page, ViewContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageActivator.Activate(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.RenderPartialViewAsync(TextWriter writer, Object model, IView view)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
>    at AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__45_1()
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
>    at AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync()
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>       Request finished in 19.4666ms 500
> ```

Could you please recommend the right approach for hosting my web app with enabled enforced encryption with Nginx?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stackoverflow. The exception is telling you have misconfigured connectionString inside `appsettings.json`. Could you check it please, 

`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I didn`t even know it was a problem with the connection to the database. I had to configure my web app for mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `connectionString` inside your `appsettings.json` when you have deployed your application on any host.

Usually connection strings are like below:

```
{
 'connectionStrings':{
   'connectionString': 'your-connection-string'
 }
}
```